# How to save data from org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame created on MongoDB data back to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

There are methods to save data of `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` to file system or Hive. But how to save data from `DataFrame` created on MongoDB data  back to MongoDB?

**Edit** : I created DataFrame using

```
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext()
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set("mongo.input.uri","mongodb://localhost:27017:testDB.testCollection);
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>> mongoJavaRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, MongoInputFormat.class, Object.class,
            BSONObject.class).toJavaRDD();
JavaRDD<Object> mongoRDD = mongoJavaRDD.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>, Object>()
    {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Object> call(Tuple2<Object, BSONObject> arg)
        {
            BSONObject obj = arg._2();
            Object javaObject = generateJavaObjectFromBSON(obj, clazz);
            return Arrays.asList(javaObject);
        }
    });

sqlContext = new SqlContext(sc);
 DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(mongoRDD, Person.class).registerTempTable("Person");
```

Comment: OK, my Java is rusty at best, but I really don't understand why to create a single element list just to `flatMap`. Simple map should be enough. Also what is going on inside `generateJavaObjectFromBSON`?

Answer (score 3):

Using PySpark and assuming you have a local MongoDB instance:

```py
import pymongo
from toolz import dissoc

# First, lets create some dummy collection
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client["foo"]["bar"].insert([{"k": "foo", "v": 1}, {"k": "bar", "v": 2}])
client.close()

config = {
    "mongo.input.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/foo.bar",
    "mongo.output.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017/foo.barplus"
}

# Read data from MongoDB
rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
    "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat",
     "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
     "org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable",
     None, None, config)

# Drop _id field and create data frame
dt = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd.map(lambda (k, v): dissoc(v, "_id")))
dt_plus_one = dt.select(dt["k"], (dt["v"] + 1).alias("v"))

(dt_plus_one.
   rdd. # Extract rdd
   map(lambda row: (None, row.asDict())). # Map to (None, dict) pairs
   saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
       "file:///placeholder", # Ignored
       # From org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop:mongo-hadoop-core
       "com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat", 
        None, None, None, None, config))
```

See also: [Getting Spark, Python, and MongoDB to work together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391840/1560062)

Comment: I am using and did not find any createDataFrame() method for the ist of json objects...

Comment: So, problem is with loading to data frame as well?