# Getting Spark, Python, and MongoDB to work together

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo

I'm having difficulty getting these components to knit together properly. I have Spark installed and working successfully, I can run jobs locally, standalone, and also via YARN. I have followed the steps advised (to the best of my knowledge) [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage) and [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/spark/src/main/python/README.rst)

I'm working on Ubuntu and the various component versions I have are

- **Spark** spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6
- **Hadoop** hadoop-2.6.1
- **Mongo** 2.6.10
- **Mongo-Hadoop connector** cloned from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop.git
- **Python** 2.7.10

I had some difficulty following the various steps such as which jars to add to which path, so what I have added are

- in `/usr/local/share/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce` **I have added** `mongo-hadoop-core-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`
- the following **environment variables**

  - `export HADOOP_HOME="/usr/local/share/hadoop-2.6.1"`
  - `export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin`
  - `export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/share/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6"`
  - `export PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/share/mongo-hadoop/spark/src/main/python"`
  - `export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin`

My Python program is basic

```python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import pymongo_spark
pymongo_spark.activate()

def main():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("pyspark test")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    rdd = sc.mongoRDD(
        'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/mydb.mycollection')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am running it using the command

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /usr/local/share/mongo-hadoop/spark/build/libs/ --master local[4] ~/sparkPythonExample/SparkPythonExample.py
```

and I am getting the following output as a result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/sparkPythonExample/SparkPythonExample.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/me/sparkPythonExample/SparkPythonExample.py", line 17, in main
    rdd = sc.mongoRDD('mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/mydb.mycollection')
  File "/usr/local/share/mongo-hadoop/spark/src/main/python/pymongo_spark.py", line 161, in mongoRDD
    return self.mongoPairRDD(connection_string, config).values()
  File "/usr/local/share/mongo-hadoop/spark/src/main/python/pymongo_spark.py", line 143, in mongoPairRDD
    _ensure_pickles(self)
  File "/usr/local/share/mongo-hadoop/spark/src/main/python/pymongo_spark.py", line 80, in _ensure_pickles
    orig_tb)
py4j.protocol.Py4JError
```

According to [here](https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/blob/master/py4j-web/advanced_topics.rst#id19)

> This exception is raised when an exception occurs in the Java client
> code. For example, if you try to pop an element from an empty stack.
> The instance of the Java exception thrown is stored in the
> java_exception member.

Looking at the source code for `pymongo_spark.py` and the line throwing the error, it says

> "Error while communicating with the JVM. Is the MongoDB Spark jar on
> Spark's CLASSPATH? : "

So in response, I have tried to be sure the right jars are being passed, but I might be doing this all wrong, see below

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --jars /usr/local/share/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/mongo-hadoop-spark-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar,/usr/local/share/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar --driver-class-path /usr/local/share/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar,/usr/local/share/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/mongo-hadoop-spark-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --master local[4] ~/sparkPythonExample/SparkPythonExample.py
```

I have imported `pymongo` to the same python program to verify that I can at least access MongoDB using that, and I can.

I know there are quite a few moving parts here so if I can provide any more useful information please let me know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Updates**:

*2016-07-04*

Since the last update [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark) matured quite a lot. It provides [up-to-date binaries](https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3Aorg.mongodb.spark) and data source based API but it is using `SparkConf` configuration so it is subjectively less flexible than the Stratio/Spark-MongoDB.

*2016-03-30*

Since the original answer I found two different ways to connect to MongoDB from Spark:

- [mongodb/mongo-spark](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark)
- [Stratio/Spark-MongoDB](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB)

While the former one seems to be relatively immature the latter one looks like a much better choice than a Mongo-Hadoop connector and provides a Spark SQL API.

```
# Adjust Scala and package version according to your setup
# although officially 0.11 supports only Spark 1.5
# I haven't encountered any issues on 1.6.1
bin/pyspark --packages com.stratio.datasource:spark-mongodb_2.11:0.11.0
```

```py
df = (sqlContext.read
  .format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb")
  .options(host="mongo:27017", database="foo", collection="bar")
  .load())

df.show()

## +---+----+--------------------+
## |  x|   y|                 _id|
## +---+----+--------------------+
## |1.0|-1.0|56fbe6f6e4120712c...|
## |0.0| 4.0|56fbe701e4120712c...|
## +---+----+--------------------+
```

It seems to be much more stable than `mongo-hadoop-spark`, supports predicate pushdown without static configuration and simply works.

**The original answer**:

Indeed, there are quite a few moving parts here. I tried to make it a little bit more manageable by building a simple  Docker image which roughly matches described configuration (I've omitted Hadoop libraries for brevity though). You can find [complete source on `GitHub`](https://github.com/zero323/docker-mongo-spark) ([DOI 10.5281/zenodo.47882](https://zenodo.org/record/47882)) and build it from scratch:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/zero323/docker-mongo-spark.git
cd docker-mongo-spark
docker build -t zero323/mongo-spark .
```

or download an image I've [pushed to Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/zero323/mongo-spark/) so you can simply `docker pull zero323/mongo-spark`):

Start images:

```sh
docker run -d --name mongo mongo:2.6
docker run -i -t --link mongo:mongo zero323/mongo-spark /bin/bash
```

Start PySpark shell passing `--jars` and `--driver-class-path`:

```
pyspark --jars ${JARS} --driver-class-path ${SPARK_DRIVER_EXTRA_CLASSPATH}
```

And finally see how it works:

```py
import pymongo
import pymongo_spark

mongo_url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017/'

client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_url)
client.foo.bar.insert_many([
    {"x": 1.0, "y": -1.0}, {"x": 0.0, "y": 4.0}])
client.close()

pymongo_spark.activate()
rdd = (sc.mongoRDD('{0}foo.bar'.format(mongo_url))
    .map(lambda doc: (doc.get('x'), doc.get('y'))))
rdd.collect()

## [(1.0, -1.0), (0.0, 4.0)]
```

Please note that mongo-hadoop seems to close the connection after the first action. So calling for example `rdd.count()` after the collect will throw an exception.

Based on different problems I've encountered creating this image I tend to believe that **passing** `mongo-hadoop-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `mongo-hadoop-spark-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` **to both** `--jars` and `--driver-class-path` **is the only hard requirement**.

**Notes**:

- This image is loosely based on [jaceklaskowski/docker-spark](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/docker-spark)
   so please be sure to send some good karma to [@jacek-laskowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305344/jacek-laskowski) if it helps.
- If don't require a development version including [new API](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage#python-example-unreleasedin-master-branch) then using `--packages` is most likely a better option.

Comment: Quick question (if I should move this to a new question just say). How do I authenticate to mongo using pymongo_spark, I have tried the standard mongo connection uri approach `mongo_rdd = sc.mongoRDD('mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/db.collection')` but it's not working

Comment: To be honest I don't know. Passing in uri [should work](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Usage-with-Authentication#basic-configuration-for-the-connector). You can try to pass them in a config dictionary `sc.mongoRDD(uri, some_config)` but it is just a guess.

Comment: Turns out [this is my problem](http://pauldone.blogspot.ie/2014/05/mongodb-connector-authentication.html). I'm working through the fix now. Thanks again

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add a write example, in addition to the read one you've given.

Comment: MongoDB user should have the right to execute splitvector command over the collection. See clusterManager role in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/.    And, for writing the rdd to mongodb, use 
`new_rdd.saveToMongoDB(out_path)`

Comment: @zero323 I followed the docker image from [josemyd](https://hub.docker.com/r/josemyd/docker-spark-mongo/), but it needs some jar files. How and where can I download them?

Answer (score 3):

Can you try using `--package` option instead of `--jars ...` in your spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --packages org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop:mongo-hadoop-core:1.3.1,org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.1.0 [REST OF YOUR OPTIONS]
```

Some of these jar files are not Uber jars and need more dependencies to be downloaded before that can get to work.

Comment: I get the following error referring to failed downloads `:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [download failed: com.google.guava#guava;11.0.2!guava.jar, ......`

Comment: Maybe it was a transient problem with network. Can you try again? What is the underlying exception?

Comment: Your suggestion did work for me, but I felt @zero323 gave the more useful answer and so marked that as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem yesterday. Was able to fix it by placing `mongo-java-driver.jar` in `$HADOOP_HOME/lib` and `mongo-hadoop-core.jar` and `mongo-hadoop-spark.jar` in `$HADOOP_HOME/spark/classpath/emr` (Or any other folder that is in the `$SPARK_CLASSPATH`).

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: It doesn't seem to help, in *$HADOOP_HOME/lib* I have **mongo-java-driver-3.0.4.jar** and then in */usr/local/share/mongo-hadoop/spark/build/libs/* I have **mongo-hadoop-core-1.4.1.jar** and **mongo-hadoop-spark-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**. I pass this directory when running the job *$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /usr/local/share/mongo-hadoop/spark/build/libs/ --master local[4] ~/sparkPythonExample/SparkPythonExample.py*

Answer (score 0):

Good Luck！

@see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Spark-Usage

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

import pymongo_spark
# Important: activate pymongo_spark.
pymongo_spark.activate()


def main():
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("pyspark test")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

    # Create an RDD backed by the MongoDB collection.
    # This RDD *does not* contain key/value pairs, just documents.
    # If you want key/value pairs, use the mongoPairRDD method instead.
    rdd = sc.mongoRDD('mongodb://localhost:27017/db.collection')

    # Save this RDD back to MongoDB as a different collection.
    rdd.saveToMongoDB('mongodb://localhost:27017/db.other.collection')

    # You can also read and write BSON:
    bson_rdd = sc.BSONFileRDD('/path/to/file.bson')
    bson_rdd.saveToBSON('/path/to/bson/output')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```