# MongoDB query filters using Stratio's Spark-MongoDB library

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, stratio

I'm trying to query a MongoDB collection using Stratio's Spark-MongoDB [library](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB). I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391840/getting-spark-python-and-mongodb-to-work-together) thread to get started with and I'm currently running the following piece of code:

```
reader = sqlContext.read.format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb")
data = reader.options(host='<ip>:27017', database='<db>', collection='<col>').load()
```

This will load the whole collection into Spark dataframe and as the collection is large, it's a taking a lot of time. Is there any way to specify query filters and load only selected data into Spark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark dataframe processing requires schema knowledge. When working with data sources with flexible and/or unknown schema, before Spark can do anything with the data, it has to discover its schema. This is what `load()` does. It looks at the data only for the purpose of discovering the schema of `data`. When you perform an action on `data`, e.g., `collect()`, Spark will actually read the data for processing purposes.

There is only one way to radically speed up `load()` and that's by providing the schema yourself and thus obviating the need for schema discovery. Here is an example taken from [the library documentation](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-mongodb/blob/master/doc/src/site/sphinx/First_Steps.rst#scala-api):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schemaMongo = StructType(StructField("name", StringType, true) :: StructField("age", IntegerType, true ) :: Nil)
val df = sqlContext.read.schema(schemaMongo).format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb").options(Map("host" -> "localhost:27017", "database" -> "highschool", "collection" -> "students")).load
```

You can get a slight gain by sampling only a fraction of the documents in the collection by setting the `schema_samplingRatio` configuration parameter to a value less than the `1.0` default. However, since Mongo doesn't have sampling built in, you'll still be accessing potentially a lot of data.