# How to tell PySpark where the pymongo-spark package is located?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I'm creating a Data Science env't on a laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The instructions are in Chapter 2 of [Agile Data Science](https://github.com/rjurney/Agile_Data_Code_2) by Russell Jurney.

I need to configure PySpark to talk to MongoDB using the [mongo-hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) package.

So far, so good. The git repo currently resides in my home directory. PyMongo is already installed as well.

[image: mongo-hadoop installation:]

Building mongo-hadoop-spark.jar also seems to have gone well. I placed a copy in my PySpark system class path; the PySparkShell indicates the .jar is in place:

[image: mongo-hadoop-spark jar file]

However, PySpark is still having trouble finding the package:

[image: PySpark session]

This is my first attempt at installing these tools, and I'm floundering. Suggestions?

Comment: you had to copy the jar file inside spark_home/jars directory and not in python directory

Comment: Have you tried [Getting Spark, Python, and MongoDB to work together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33391840/8371915)?